# Using each in ember Handlebars

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have an each loop like the below, I want to add a '(' before the first element and ')' after the last element. Can somebody please help me how can I do it? Any help would be very very helpful - thanks

```
{{#each  v.NOVNoticeTypeName as |vv iindex|}}
    {{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}}
    <br/>                                         
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) just check if the element is the first or last in the array (not sure exactly what you wanted to do with the ( and ) so I just took a guess:

```
{{#each  v.NOVNoticeTypeName as |vv iindex|}}
  {{#if (or (eq v.NOVNoticeTypeName.firstObject vv) (eq v.NOVNoticeTypeName.lastObject vv))}}
    ({{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}})
  {{else}}
    {{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}}
  {{/if}}
  <br/>                                         
{{/each}}
```

Comment: When I ran this: ember install ember-truth-helpers on VS code prompt, I am getting error as below: ember : The term 'ember' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ ember install ember-truth-helpers
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ember:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException, any help my friend

Comment: @Abdul do you have ember-cli installed? https://ember-cli.com/

Comment: How would I know if it is installed or not? I am able to run the ember application, but its in Visual Studio though.

Comment: how do you run `ember serve`? You can also try `npm run ember install ember-truth-helpers` or `yarn run ember install ember-truth-helpers`

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error my friend: when I run: npm run ember install ember-truth-helpers "npm ERR! missing script: ember
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aaleem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-08T19_59_21_183Z-debug.log" - any help please - thank you.

Comment: And when I ran this command: yarn run ember install ember-truth-helpers I got the following error "yarn run v1.19.0
error Command "ember" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command" - any help please - thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do ‘npm install -g ember-cli’

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a combination of [ember-truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers) and [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#has-next)'s `has-next` and `has-previous`.

```
{{#each v.NOVNoticeTypeName as |vv iindex|}}
  {{#if (not (has-previous vv v.NOVNoticeTypeName))}}
    {{!-- This is the first element in the array}} --}}
    ({{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}}
  {{else if (not (has-next vv v.NOVNoticeTypeName))}}
    {{!-- This is the last element in the array}} --}}
    {{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}})
  {{else}}
    {{!-- This is everything except the first and last element --}}
    {{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}: {{get v.NOVNumber iindex}}
  {{/if}}
  <br />
{{/each}}
```

Comment: In addition, I believe that you could simplify it slightly by using `{{vv}}` instead of `{{get v.NOVNoticeTypeName iindex}}` inside of your each block.

Comment: Hi, I am getting the following error my friend: when I run: npm run ember install ember-truth-helpers "npm ERR! missing script: ember npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR! C:\Users\aaleem\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-11-08T19_59_21_183Z-debug.log" - any help please - thank you

Comment: And when I ran this command: yarn run ember install ember-truth-helpers I got the following error "yarn run v1.19.0 error Command "ember" not found. info Visit yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command" - any help please - thanks in advance.

Comment: @Abdul You don't need to run `npm run ember install ember-truth-helpers`, it should just be `ember install ember-truth-helpers`

Comment: @Abdul could you also tell me what the output is when you run `ember -v`?

Comment: @Abdul Any updates? Were you able to get it working?